# Maximum number of outstanding loadLeaderboardsWithCompletionHandler: from a single iOS client?

Tags: ios, parallel-processing, ios8, thread-safety, game-center

I am trying to fill a table that shows leaderboard sets along with their titles and numbers of contained leaderboards. (Similar to what the Game Center app also does.)

In order to fill the table, I send off many `loadLeaderboardsWithCompletionHandler:` requests to instances of `GKLeaderboard` in parallel. It appears that for the first dozen or so parallel calls the completion handler receives expected values, but for later ones it receives `nil` for both `leaderboards` and `error`.

Could it be that there is a maximum number of parallel `loadLeaderboardsWithCompletionHandler:` requests that may be outstanding (from a single client), and are specific limitations of this kind documented by Apple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried combinations of the following remedies:

1. throttle to only one or few parallel requests
2. enforce delay between requests
3. repeat requests for a number of times until `leaderboards` is no longer `nil`

A combination of throttling to only 1 "parallel" request and repeating requests up to 2 times proved effective for a set of approx. 20 leaderboards.